# Why does remainder theorem works?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

If we divide the polynomial $f(x)$ by $(x - a)$, we get a remainder $r$ and a quotient $g(x)$. So, $f(x)$ can be written as,
$$f(x) = (x - a) g(x) + r$$
If $x=a$ then,
$f(a) = (a - a) g(x) + r$
or, $f(a) = r$.

It is a clear proof of the remainder theorem. But unfortunately, I don't find it intuitive.

Can you show me any "intuitive" way to prove the remainder theorem?

Comment: Why are you putting each mathematical expression within a pair of `$$...$$`'s? In most cases, a simple `$...$` is better.

Comment: What part specifically do you not understand?

Comment: How would "intuitive" be better than "clear"?

Comment: In the context that one first hears about this, it is a genuinely new idea, indeed! So it does _not_ reduce to previous things!

Comment: If you feel comfortable about that the remainder of dividing a polynomial $g(y)$ by $y$ = the constant term of $g$ = $g(0)$, the remainder theorem is just the same thing, but with a change of variable $y=x-a$.

Comment: Are you familiar with long division of  polynomials? What happens when you divide a polynomial by the polynomial $x - a$?

Answer (score 4):

If it helps, a nice way to think about it is that $(x-a)$ is a factor of $f(x)-f(a)$. This is often called the 'factor theorem'.

If this is not unconvincing, note that plugging in $x=a$ gives $f(x)-f(a) = 0$ for obvious reasons, so $x=a$ is a root of the polynomial $g(x) = f(x)-f(a)$, which we know means that $(x-a)$ is a factor of $f(x)-f(a)$. Or else, you can see more directly by observing that $x^k - a^k = (x-a)(x^{k-1} + x^{k-2}a + \dots + a^{k-1})$, so the difference of each $k$th power term in $f(x)$ and $f(a)$ will be divisible by $(x-a)$.

In any case, if $x-a$ divides $f(x)-f(a)$, then $f(x)-f(a) = (x-a)h(x)$, where $h(x)$ is the other factors. Therefore, $f(x) = (x-a)h(x) + f(a)$, so the remainder is indeed $f(a)$.

If you want more detail you will need to ask for it.

Answer (score 0):

Write

$$f(x) = c_nx^n + c_{n - 1}x^{n - 1} + \dots + c_1x +c_0$$

You want a polynomial $g(x) = d_{n - 1}x^{n - 1} + \dots + d_1x + d_0$ and a number $r \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x) = (x - a)g(x) + r$, that is,

\begin{equation}\label{equation}
c_nx^n + c_{n - 1}x^{n - 1} + \dots + c_1x +c_0 = (x - a)(d_{n - 1}x^{n - 1} + \dots + d_1x + d_0) + r
\end{equation}

The polynomials in the left and right hand side are equal if, and only if they have the same coefficients.

The coefficient of $x^n$ in the right-hand side is $d_{n - 1}$, so we must have $d_{n - 1} = c_n$.

If $1 \leq k \leq n - 1$, the coefficient of $x^k$ in the right hand side is $d_{k - 1} - ad_{k}$, so we have $d_{k - 1} - ad_{k} = c_k$.

Finally, the coefficient of $x^0$ in the right hand side is $r - ad_0$, so that we have $r - ad_0 = c_0$.

Using the equations

$$d_{n - 1} = c_n$$
$$d_{k - 1} - ad_{k} = c_k \text{ for }1 \leq k \leq n - 1$$
$$r - ad_0 = c_0$$

We can find the unique polynomial $g(x)$ and number $r \in \mathbb{R}$ with

$$f(x) = (x - a)g(x) + r$$